# How to filter staticman form submissions to relevant page in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm building a review site in Gatsby. My pages are created at build time from a remote API source.

I've integrated Staticman with my Gatsby build I can successfully submit a form which is then stored in /src/data/review/property-[listing_id]/review-[listing_id]-[timestamp].yml

The form submissions are yaml and I'm using gatsby-transformer-yaml with gatsby-source-filesystem to access the data through graphql.

I can query the data easily enough using `staticquery` but this returns all the submissions.

What I'm struggling with is to filter the submissions to the respective page ie the page where they were submitted.

Using graphiql with this query I get back exactly the data I want but am unable to map over it I get 'Cannot read property 'edges' of undefined'.

```
query($slug: String!) {
    property(listing_id: { eq: $slug }) {
      description
      listing_id
    }
    allReviewsYaml(
      filter: { fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } } }
      sort: { fields: date, order: DESC }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          name
          review
          listing_id
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Perhaps I'm approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: This looks right. If edges is undefined, it means (you can guess) that there is no data, but if you say you can query it in GraphiQL, there should be. Is the repository open-source? I can take a look :)

Comment: Yeah I haven't managed to rule just incorrect syntax when it comes to trying to map the results. Repo is here: https://github.com/ellis-sutehall/rent-review Thanks very much for taking a look. You'll see a few files property.js and reviews.js are what you're interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into your [repository](https://github.com/ellis-sutehall/rent-review/tree/0fb37b7d7ca6468684b226ad432e52b853308d74), let me try to summarize what you've tried so far:

1. You are creating property pages using in `gatsby-node.js`, passing a `propertyId` via context to your `property.js` page template
2. In the `property.js` template, you're querying property data and its reviews using a [Gatsby page query](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/page-query/)
3. In the `reviews.js` component, you're rendering reviews based on the `propertyId` using the [Gatsby useStaticQuery hook](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/use-static-query/)

### Fixing `Cannot read property 'edges' of undefined`

Back to your question:

> Perhaps I'm approaching this the wrong way?

Good news: your approach is fine!

> Using graphiql with this query I get back exactly the data I want but am unable to map over it I get 'Cannot read property 'edges' of undefined'.

After looking at your code, I assume you're talking about [these lines](https://github.com/ellis-sutehall/rent-review/blob/0fb37b7d7ca6468684b226ad432e52b853308d74/src/templates/property.js#L83-L85). Here's a simplified reproduction:

```js
export const query = graphql`
  yourQuery {}
`

const Property = (props) => {
  query.allReviewsYaml.edges.map(edge => (
    <p>{edge.node.name}</p>
  ))
}
```

You're trying to access the results of a Gatsby page query (see step 2 above), but `allReviewsYaml` is `undefined`.

The solution: **you can access the results of the Gatsby page query via props**:

```js
export const query = graphql`
  yourQuery {}
`

const Property = (props) => {
  // results of an exported GraphQL page query are exposed in `props.data`
  props.data.allReviewsYaml.edges.map(edge => (
    <p>{edge.node.name}</p>
  ))
}
```

From the Gatsby docs on [Querying data in pages with GraphQL](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/page-query/#provide-data-to-the-homepage--component):

> The data prop contains the results of the GraphQL query, and matches the shape you would expect.

*Note: I've submitted [a PR](https://github.com/ellis-sutehall/rent-review/pull/11) to your repository for you to test the solution. You can see the query results from `property.js` being rendered on http://localhost:8000/property/52882945, for example.*

### Caveat about variables in `useStaticQuery`

The next logical step from here is to render reviews in a separate `Reviews` component (see step 3 above).

Your use of the `useStaticQuery` hook is good, but it won't work in your case: [`useStaticQuery` cannot take a variable](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/use-static-query/#known-limitations) ([yet](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10482)).

This means that you will not be able to pass your `reviews.js` component a `propertyId` prop to query and render all property reviews.

What you should do instead is query all the necessary data in the page query (i.e. in your `property.js`), and pass the data down to a stateless `Review` (not `Reviews`) component.

It would look something like this (this is your `property.js`):

```js
export const query = graphql`
  yourQuery {
    // here, query all property AND review data
  }
`

const Property = ({ data }) => {
  // render the property page
  // ...

  // render the reviews
  data.allReviewsYaml.edges.map({ node } => {
    // TODO build the `Review` component
    return (
      <Review review={node} />
    )
  )
}
```

I hope my answer brought some useful context and solutions for querying data with GraphQL in Gatsby! Don't hesitate to comment or post a new question if you encounter new issues.

Have fun building with Gatsby!

Comment: Wow, what can I say? Thank you so much you went well above and beyond what I was expecting. Not just with the problem but the advice. I've got a good bit more to do but this is a great help, thanks again.

Comment: Happy to help! Feel free to open a new question if anything else comes up. Cheers!